# Access the values of dictionaries in a list, then print them nicely

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing

I have a list of dictionaries from which I need to extract information, and then print it out in a special format.

```
dict_list = [
    {'description' : 'item 1',
     'amount' : int_amount1
},
    {'description' : 'item 2',
     'amount' : int_amount2
},
    {'description' : 'item 3', 
     'amount' : int_amount3
]
```

I need to access the values in these dictionaries and print them out in the following way:

```
'item 1'       int_amount1
'item 2'       int_amount2
'item 3'       int_amount3
```

If possible I would also need to print each key value at 20 characters max.
Thus far I have tried for loops and list comprehensions but the farthest I've gotten is just printing out all the values in a one by one list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate over the `list` and do your printing for each item

```
dict_list = [
    {'description': 'item 1', 'amount': 'int_amount1'},
    {'description': 'item 2', 'amount': 'int_amount2'},
    {'description': 'item 3', 'amount': 'int_amount3'}
]

for item in dict_list:
    print(f"{item['description']:20s}{item['amount']:20s}")
```

Giving

```
item 1              int_amount1
item 2              int_amount2
item 3              int_amount3
```

Comment: Ah can't believe it was that simple. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @不苦労真 You can now think about accepting the answer ;)

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't realize I hadn't

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_list = [
    {'description': 'item 1', 'amount': 'int_amount1'},
    {'description': 'item 2', 'amount': 'int_amount2'},
    {'description': 'item 3', 'amount': 'int_amount3'}
]

spaces = 20 * " "
for item in dict_list:
    print(f"{item['description']}{spaces}{item['amount']}")
```

should work fine because it gives you:

```
item 1                    int_amount1
item 2                    int_amount2
item 3                    int_amount3
```